# Chartjs Datasets overlapping and z-index

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I have the below Chart implemented using chart.js version 3.x.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxya0u98/12/

I have multiple datasets in my charts to achieve the behavior I want.

I am facing an issue with the datasets overlapping. In the chart, I have end of the `blue color line` overlapping with the `green color dot` dataset. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

I have the below two datasets:

```
// Data set for the Big Dot
{
   showLine: false,
   borderWidth: 0,
   lineTension: 0,
   borderColor: colorVal,
   backgroundColor: colorVal,
   pointBackgroundColor: colorVal,
   pointBorderColor: colorVal,
   pointBorderWidth: 2,
   pointRadius: 15,
};

// Data set for the Connecting Lines
{
   showLine: true,
   lineTension: 0,
   borderWidth: 5,
   borderColor: colorVal,
   pointRadius: 0,
   pointBorderWidth: 0,
   spanGaps: true,
};
```

Is there a Z-Index for the Datasets so that they appear on top of the previous one in the stack?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The option [`dataset.order`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#general) has similar effect as the `z-index`.

- Datasets with higher `order` are drawn first
- Datasets with no or lower order are drawn last, hence appear on top

Therefore, adding `order: 1` to your line datasets should solve the problem.

```
var newDataLine = {
  ...
  order: 1
};
```

Comment: I was also searching in the documentation but I was not able to find it. It will be helpful if you can post the link to the documentation.

Comment: In my answer, `dataset.order` is already linked to the corresponding section in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining multiple datasets, you could proceed as follows:

- First convert your line chart into a scatter chart.
- Then draw the lines directly on the canvas using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. You can use the `beforeDraw` hook to draw connection lines of different colors between data points and to the open end of the chart.

> Note that you have to define `xAxes.ticks.max` in order to obtain the open end line at the right of the chart.

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: "scatter",
  plugins: [{
    beforeDraw: chart => {
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      ctx.save();
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];
      var dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
      var y = yAxis.getPixelForValue(0);
      dataset.data.forEach((value, index) => {
        var xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForValue(value.x);
        var xTo;
        if (index + 1 < dataset.data.size) {
          xTo = xAxis.getPixelForValue(dataset.data[index + 1].x);
        } else {
          xTo = xAxis.right;
        }        
        ctx.strokeStyle = dataset.backgroundColor[index];
        ctx.lineWidth = 4;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(xFrom, y);
        ctx.lineTo(xTo, y);
        ctx.stroke();        
      });
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 1, y: 0 },
        { x: 2, y: 0 }
      ],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
      borderColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
      pointRadius: 8,
      pointHoverRadius: 8,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        left: 10,
        right: 10
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          max: 3
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="30"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but using the above solution breaks the behaviour that I want to have in the chart. Is there a way we can simply set the z-index of the datasets in the chart?